# Linux file system reaction on files being removed externally via samba

Tags: debian, files

I have question about how/when files on SAMBA are refreshed

I'm doing something like that:

```
me@server:~/test/application

me@server:~/test/application$ dotnet myapp.dll

Application prints hello world
```

now I'm removing folder `application` using `Windows` (it's connected via `SAMBA`) 
and I'm inserting there the same folder, at the same place with my new application inside.

now I'm going back to my Linux terminal (connected via SSH) which stays in the same path `/test/application/` and using

```
dotnet myapp.dll
```

results in:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.
   at Interop.Sys.GetCwdHelper(Byte* ptr, Int32 bufferSize)
   at Interop.Sys.GetCwd()
   at System.Environment.get_CurrentDirectory()
   at System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.CommandResolver.TryResolveCommandSpec(ICommandResolverPolicy commandResolverPolicy, String commandName, IEnumerable`1 args, NuGetFramework framework, String configuration, String outputPath, String applicationName)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.Command.Create(ICommandResolverPolicy commandResolverPolicy, String commandName, IEnumerable`1 args, NuGetFramework framework, String configuration, String outputPath, String applicationName)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.Command.Create(String commandName, IEnumerable`1 args, NuGetFramework framework, String configuration, String outputPath, String applicationName)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

It seems like something is wrong with my app, but

**using `ls` to list files shows nothing - as if folder was empty,**

But after doing `cd ..` and then `cd application` everything works properly (ls lists my files, app works properly)

Basically it requires "refreshing folder", but what's the reason of that under the hood?

Friend told me that there was something like "old folder session with previous disk INodes loaded"

Comment: Your friend is right.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux or Unix you can delete a file or directory that is still opened by a process.

In your case the shell has still the old `/test/application` open as its current directory.

Via samba you have deleted all files and the directory entry `application`  in the parent directory `/test`. The inode of this directory is still in use by the shell, and the shell passes this current directory to its child processes, e.g. `ls`. `ls` correctly lists no files because you have deleted them from the directory file that used to be `/test/application`.

When you use `cd application` in `/test`, the directory file `/test` is read which contains a new entry `application` pointing to the newly created `/test/application`.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/2028874/10622916